# Cannot open Utilities 'FilterOptions'

Tags: format, fortran

I'm trying to run a code like this in Mathematica:

```
(* initialize everything *)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

(* all *nb are in $WorkingDirectory *)
$WorkingDirectory = "/Users/U1/Workspace/BCOASMBH/Core/Fortran/"
(* Load Assumptions and format.m *)
Get[FileNameJoin[{$WorkingDirectory, "TemplateForHamiltonian.nb"}]];
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Get: Cannot open Utilities`FilterOptions`.
Needs: Context Utilities`FilterOptions` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
==========================
Example Script For Writing
==========================
filename = "testing.f" 
stmp = OpenWrite[filename, FormatType -> OutputForm];
Write[stmp, FortranAssign[VariableInFortran, FormulaInMathematica, \
AssignPrecision -> 16, AssignTemporary -> {t, Array}]];
Close[stmp];
```

I have tried to write:

```
Begin["Private`"];
FilterOptions[s_, r___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[Flatten[{r}], Options[s]];
```

Which some posts on Stack have suggested but nothing seems to work. I use Windows and have Mathematica v.12.

Comment: You also need to find the ``Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"]`` somewhere and remove it.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where I might find Needs["Utilities`FilterOptions`"] ?

Comment: You should read the posts you found more carefully. It should be in one or more files you `Get`. (If I have to guess, it may be in the format.m file. ) Also, notice the `FilterOptions[s_, r___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[Flatten[{r}], Options[s]];` should be put there, too.